# Bash date query stopped working

Tags: bash, shell, date, ansible

A few months ago I wrote a some bash to get dates. I needed these dates as facts in an ansible script to later use them to get data from the database. This worked fine until today here is the code:

```
- name: Set date variables
set_fact:
  first_day_last_month: "{{lookup('pipe','date -d \"-1 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days\" +%Y-%m-%d')}}"
  last_day_last_month: "{{lookup('pipe','date -d \"$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 day\" +%Y-%m-%d')}}"
  first_day_current_month: "{{lookup('pipe','date -d \"-$(($(date +%d)-1)) days\" +%Y-%m-%d')}}"
  last_day_current_month: "{{lookup('pipe','date -d \"-$(date +%d) days +1 month\"  +%Y-%m-%d')}}"
```

However when I run this now I get an error: 
/bin/sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "08-1"

I tried debugging it on the bash command line:

```
seven@monstermachine:~$ echo $(date -d "-$($(date +%d)-1)")
08-1: command not found
Mit Nov 8 00:00:00 CET 2017
```

but until now i'm not getting it fixed.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Your debugging command misses a set of parentheses: $(( )) arithmethic is with two sets of parentheses.

Comment: @marcolz : yep agree, but I notice that *some* of the problem code provided (besides the debugging step) have only `$(date ..)`. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%d` is zero padded which gives base eight or octal number and `08` is not a valid octal number which thows an error.

What you need is something like :

```
echo $(date -d "$(($(date +%e)-1))")
Wed Nov 8 07:00:00 IST 2017
```

Note `%e` will cause date to be space padded which is equivalent to `%_d`.

To perform a mathematical expression use `$(( expression ))` format. I didn't understand the actual logic behind your code, so make sure your code fits the logic.

Answer (score 3):

To get `first_day_current_month` in your script, you could use:

```
date +%Y-%m-01
```

similar for the others, for example to get `last_day_last_month`:

```
date -d `date +%Y-%m-01`"-1 day" +%Y-%m-%d
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help I will make use of both of your answers to come up with a better working command.